# How to manually define the page header with scrheadings?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I want to manually define my headings in a two-side document as follows:

On the odd pages, I want to have the page number and the (hard-copied) title of my whole document ("TITLE OF THIS STUDY")

On the even pages, I want to have the page number and the automatically selected section title (without the section number).

I already managed to implement the odd page style, but fail to implement the even pages. Do I need to define a sectionmark?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lohead*{\bfseries\pagemark \quad Title of this study}
\lehead*{\bfseries\pagemark \quad \sectionmark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Title of this study}
\maketitle
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

odd/even pages make only sense in `twoside` mode. `\sectionmark` is a command to *store* a mark, not to output it. You need e.g. `\headmark` for this. To remove the number you can redefine `\sectionmarkformat`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lohead*{\bfseries\pagemark \quad Title of this study}
\lehead*{\bfseries\pagemark \quad \headmark}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{} % no number
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Title of this study}
\maketitle
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well!